# cucumber extent report plugin - NPE when setting parameters as system properties instead of using extent.properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, executable-jar, extentreports

I am creating a cucumber project with extent reporting. I have used the cucumber extent adapter 5 plugin. All is working fine while I use extent.properties file for configuration. But when I set the system properties as shown below (instead of properties file)

```
System.setProperty("extent.reporter.spark.start", "true");
System.setProperty("extent.reporter.spark.config", "spark-config.xml");
System.setProperty("extent.reporter.spark.out", "test-output/sparkReport/");
System.setProperty("extent.reporter.spark.base64imagesrc", "true");
    }
```

I get an NPE from extent-adapter service class from the below method, even though I have set the value using system properties.

```
 private static void sparkBase64PngImageStyle() {
      if ("true".equals(String.valueOf(ExtentService.properties.getOrDefault("extent.reporter.spark.base64imagesrc", "false"))))
        ENABLE_BASE64_IMAGE_SRC = true; 
    }
```

Error:

**com.aventstack.extentreports.service.ExtentService.Access$400() returned null**

Any pointers will be really helpful. Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I was able to make it work with the exported JAR.

1. created a package as com.aventstack.adapter and placed the properties file in this package
2. Placed the spark-config.xml file in the same folder as the exported JAR file

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the Properties from the TestRunner class file in the before class , it will not work because the inner class to initialize these prperies run before the pointer comes to the before class .

But you can achieve this by below 2 options .

1. add configuration in the pom.xml as below .

   <systemPropertyVariables<extent.reporter.spark.start>true</extent.reporter.spark.start>
   <extent.reporter.spark.out>testoutput/SparkReport/Spark.html</extent.reporter.spark.out>
2. Send the command from for the configuration from the maven command .

mvn clean install -DargLine="-Dextent.reporter.spark.start=true -Dextent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/Spark.html"

Refer to the below link for detailed implementation .

https://ghchirp.tech/3196/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried adding the config in pom.xml but it's not taken in to consideration, or atleast am doing it wrong. And I tried to pass this as parameters but to no avail..

Comment: I finally resolved it by creating a package as com.aventstack.adapter and placing the properties file in this package and placing the spark-config.xml file in the same folder as the exported JAR file.